# Javascript - file upload securtiy check for maleware, virus

Tags: javascript, angularjs, security, file-upload

In the application multiple users are able to upload files. We need to check that they don't upload maleware or viruses to the platform. Is there an existing module or method which does this?

Comment: I use this one: https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload , make sure you use server side validation as well.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to check whether file is virus or not on the  front-end side. you can do that on backend like gmail does.

Answer (score 2):

There are several different ways to check if a file is what the user claims it is. Blueimp has a fairly popular jQuery plugin that should do the job. This plugin does the work of checking that the actual file contents and type match the extension and mime-type provided by the user.

https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

You can probably find others if you look. However, I should say that you should really be doing this validation on the back-end. As a general rule, don't do front-end validation for security; do it for user experience.

If you're using something that DOES protect against the sort of thing I describe (REST with JWT or some such) let me know and I'll ammend my answer.